# Why do you think Pakistani LACM and SLCM have different ranges?

Tags: missiles, pakistan

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babur_(cruise_missile)

The following is the picture of Pakistan's LACM Babur-II. Its billed range is 750 km.

[image]

The following is the picture of Pakistan's SLCM Babur-III. Its billed range is 450 km.

[image]

**Why could the range of Babur-III possibly be smaller than that of Babur-II?**

Comment: I would recommend you follow the [Weapons](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/102381/weapons) proposal as this question would probably be on topic there if it makes it as a full Stack Exchange site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, the changes needed to make the missile sea-launchable affected the range by either decreasing the size (fuel capacity) or increasing the weight of the missile, or both. Launching an air-breathing missile by first shooting it through the water is significantly different than launching it straight into the atmosphere from the land-mobile launcher, so it isn't surprising that other changes had to be made to the missile itself -- changes that reduce its range.